# How to display a text file in the terminal with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printf

I have 2 files in my folder:
`text.txt`
`main.py`

I want to show the text written in `text.txt` in the terminal when `main.py` is run.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```